# one users account for multiple websites how to manage session in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, authentication, google-signin

I have multiple websites, login those websites using common User Name and Password, same as Google login for Gmail, Youtube, Analytics...

All my websites developed in Asp.Net MVC, how to manage session for all other website once I have successfully login to one webiste ("Same as Google" login service).

- I am excepting better approach
- How to manage session for multiple websites?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to have shared session between multiple websites?

Comment: yes your are correct!